# Solr edismax wildcard search does not find original string

Tags: solr, edismax

I have next content in my Solr index:
`west indian cherry` in filed of type `text_en` (see below for field definition).

When I search with `cherr*` match is found.
Also search for `cherri*` matches word in document.
But search for `cherry*` does **not** match.

I suspect [`PorterStemFilterFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.PorterStemFilterFactory) for this, but I don't understand why (query analyzer is same as index analyzer).

---

### sample query

```
/solr/select?defType=edismax&q=cherry*
```

### solrconfig.xml

```
...
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
...
```

### field analysis

#### index

```
org.apache.solr.analysis.StandardTokenizerFactory: cherry
org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory: cherry
org.apache.solr.analysis.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory: cherry
org.apache.solr.analysis.PorterStemFilterFactory: cherri <-- note the change from cherry to cherri
```

#### query

```
org.apache.solr.analysis.StandardTokenizerFactory: cherry
org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory: cherry
org.apache.solr.analysis.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory: cherry
org.apache.solr.analysis.PorterStemFilterFactory: cherri
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers mentions -

> On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the
>   search word.

So the search query will not undergo any analysis during query time.
Hence the terms indexed would be different from the ones being search upon.

As the indexed term is `cherri`, the search for `cherry*` would not match any documents.